# Bidirectional Many to many association on Sails.js

Tags: javascript, orm, many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

I'm starting to use Sails.js (I'm an absolute newbie), and I want to create the following class model.
I have a `Student` and a `SubscriptionList`. The Student has a Collection of `subscriptionLists` to which he/she is subscribed, and the SubscriptionList knows all the Students that are subscribed to it. So, it's a bidirectional many-to-many association.
I created the models using these generators:

```
sails generate model Student firstName:string lastName:string fileNumber:string career:string regid:string email:email

sails generate model SubscriptionList name:string description:string
```

Since I don't know how to run a migration in Sails (I did something similar to this in Rails in the past), after that I went to the model's files, and add this:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},

subscriptionLists:{
  collection: "subscriptionLists",
  via: "students"
}
```

to the `Student` model, and this:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},

students:{
  collection: "students",
  via: "subscriptionLists"
}
```

to the `SubscriptionList` model, and run `sails lift` from the console. I got this error:

```
Error: Collection student has an attribute named subscriptionLists that is pointing to a collection named subscriptionlists which doesn't exist. You must  first create the subscriptionlists collection.
```

Which makes sense, since I'm trying to create both ends of the relationship at a time (for what I understand).
So, how can I create a bidirectional many-to-many relationship, without passing through an intermediate entity (I mean, just using a regular cross-table) in Sails.js?

Any help will be highly appreciate.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a many to many relationship in sails/waterline, a join table is built for you. Your issue is a typo. The collection you specify needs to match the model name of the model it's pointing to. You have pluralized yours. Needs to be like this:

Student:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},

subscriptionLists:{
  collection: "subscriptionList", // match model name here
  via: "students", // match attribute name on other model
  dominant: true // dominant side
}
```

SubscriptionList:

```
id: {
  type: 'integer',
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},

students:{
  collection: "student", // match model name
  via: "subscriptionLists" // match attribute name
}
```

[See the docs](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html)

Comment: If you're used to things being pluralized the way Rails does it, you can get Sails to do something similar by setting `pluralize: true` in config/blueprints.js.  I used it for a little while when I started with Sails, but I stopped because I found myself getting confused a lot.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think you should need the ```dominant: true``` unless you're using two databases. At least that's what it says here: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/Dominance.html?q=what-about-noncrossadapter-associations

Comment: This is only a problem because both sides of the association have a via modifier specified!! In the absence of via, a collection attribute always behaves as dominant: true. See the FAQ below for more information.
I think I'm in that situation right now, so I'll just keep it there for now ;)